# Print current post category during WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, terms

How do I print the current post category names so that I can output them as ID's within the HTML, with a space between each category name.

I currently have the code:

```
                <?php
                  $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'work',
                    'posts_per_page' => '9'
                  );
                  $work_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                  if ( $work_loop->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $work_loop->have_posts() ) : $work_loop->the_post();
                      // Set variables
                        $cat_ids                = get_the_ID();
                        $cat_names_array        = get_the_category($ids);
                        $work_title             = get_field( 'work_title' );
                        $work_main_image        = get_field( 'work_main_image' );
                        $work_link              = get_field( 'work_title' );
                        $work_about             = get_field( 'work_about' );
                        // $work_category = get_the_terms( the_post()->ID, 'taxonomy' );
                      // Output
                      ?>
                      <a href="<?php echo $work_main_image['url']; ?>" class="single_item link <?php print_r(array_values($cat_names_array)); ?> col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                        <img src="<?php echo $work_main_image['url']; ?>" alt=""> 
                    </a>
                    <?php
                      endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                  endif; 
                ?>
```

Which outputs:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/josh-richa/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/work-6.jpg" class="single_item link Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 2
            [name] => Web Design
            [slug] => web-design
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 2
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Web Design
            [category_nicename] => web-design
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Web Development
            [slug] => web-development
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 3
            [category_count] => 2
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Web Development
            [category_nicename] => web-development
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
 col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.3s; animation-name: fadeInUp; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                            <img src="http://localhost:8888/josh-richa/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/work-6.jpg" alt=""> 
                        </a>
```

I want the "category_nicename" from each array seperated by a space.

Comment: are you using the generic category or a custom taxonomy?

Comment: Using a generic category. I updated the code with my latest and seem to be able to get the arrays displaying but now need to grab the "category_nicename"s with a space between each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `get_the_terms()` but this function is used to get the custom taxonomies.

Use the function `get_the_category();` inside the WordPress loop and pass the `get_the_ID()` function which will get the current post ID in the loop.

get_the_category(get_the_ID());

```
                <?php
                  $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'work',
                    'posts_per_page' => '9'
                  );
                  $work_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                  if ( $work_loop->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $work_loop->have_posts() ) : $work_loop->the_post();
                      // Set variables
                        $cat_ids                = get_the_ID();
                        $cat_names_array        = get_the_category($ids);
                        $work_category           = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
                        $work_title             = get_field( 'work_title' );
                        $work_main_image        = get_field( 'work_main_image' );
                        $work_link              = get_field( 'work_title' );
                        $work_about             = get_field( 'work_about' );
                        // $work_category = get_the_terms( the_post()->ID, 'taxonomy' );
                      // Output
                      ?>
                      <a href="<?php echo $work_main_image['url']; ?>" class="single_item link <?php foreach ( $work_category as $key => $value) { echo $value->category_nicename . " "; } ?> col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                        <img src="<?php echo $work_main_image['url']; ?>" alt=""> 
                    </a>
                    <?php
                      endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                  endif; 
                ?>
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Nice! One step closer but this returns an array. How do I print each value containing the category name separated by a space....? I got one step closer and updated my code above.

Comment: @ JoshRicha I have updated the code.

Comment: Nice I had to change one part of it: 

Now, how do I add a space between each value?

<?php foreach ( $work_category as $key => $value) { echo $value->category_nicename; } ?>

It currently returns: class="single_item link web-designweb-development col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" with no space between "web-designweb-development"

Comment: Thanks sorted! Just need to add a space to the return value. Do you think I should have this code in a fucntion?

Comment: echo $value->cat_name. ' '; this will add the space after each category.